# Magic __get getter for static properties in PHP

Tags: php, oop, properties, getter

```
public static function __get($value)
```

does not work, and even if it did, it so happens that I already need the magic __get getter for instance properties in the same class.

This probably is a yes or no question, so, it is possible?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

Quoting the [manual page of __get](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) :

> Member overloading only works in
>   object context. These magic methods
>   will not be triggered in static
>   context. Therefore these methods can
>   not be declared static.

In PHP 5.3, [`__callStatic`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods) has been added ; but there is no `__getStatic` nor `__setStatic` yet ; even if the idea of having/coding them often comes back on the php internals@ mailling-list.

There is even a [Request for Comments: Static classes for PHP](http://wiki.php.net/rfc/static-classes)

But, still, not implemented *(yet ? )*

Comment: @webarto agreed, but considering we're in PHP land, they're top notch OOP features haha

Comment: @DejanMarjanovic they have their use cases.

Comment: Link seems broken, page is here: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/static-classes

Answer (score 21):

Maybe someone still need this:

```
static public function __callStatic($method, $args) {

  if (preg_match('/^([gs]et)([A-Z])(.*)$/', $method, $match)) {
    $reflector = new \ReflectionClass(__CLASS__);
    $property = strtolower($match[2]). $match[3];
    if ($reflector->hasProperty($property)) {
      $property = $reflector->getProperty($property);
      switch($match[1]) {
        case 'get': return $property->getValue();
        case 'set': return $property->setValue($args[0]);
      }     
    } else throw new InvalidArgumentException("Property {$property} doesn't exist");
  }
}
```

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs co: extracts static property name and tries to get or set it depending on action.

Comment: Due to the lack of comment on this answer: This requires a call to `Foo::getProp()`/`Foo::setProp()` to work. This is different than what OP asked for, which is to be able to write `Foo::$prop` and have the magic be invoked.

Answer (score 6):

Very nice mbrzuchalski.  But it seems to only work on public variables.  Just change your switch to this to allow it to access private/protected ones:

```
switch($match[1]) {
   case 'get': return self::${$property->name};
   case 'set': return self::${$property->name} = $args[0];
}
```

And you'd probably want to change the `if` statement to limit the variables that are accessible, or else it would defeat the purpose of having them be private or protected.

```
if ($reflector->hasProperty($property) && in_array($property, array("allowedBVariable1", "allowedVariable2"))) {...)
```

So for example, I have a class designed to pull various data for me out of a remote server using an ssh pear module, and I want it to make certain assumptions about the target directory based on what server it's being asked to look at.  A tweaked version of mbrzuchalski's method is perfect for that.

```
static public function __callStatic($method, $args) {
    if (preg_match('/^([gs]et)([A-Z])(.*)$/', $method, $match)) {
        $reflector = new \ReflectionClass(__CLASS__);
        $property = strtolower($match[2]). $match[3];
        if ($reflector->hasProperty($property)) {
            if ($property == "server") {
                $property = $reflector->getProperty($property);
                switch($match[1]) {
                    case 'set':
                        self::${$property->name} = $args[0];
                        if ($args[0] == "server1") self::$targetDir = "/mnt/source/";
                        elseif($args[0] == "server2") self::$targetDir = "/source/";
                        else self::$targetDir = "/";
                    case 'get': return self::${$property->name};
                }
            } else throw new InvalidArgumentException("Property {$property} is not publicly accessible.");
        } else throw new InvalidArgumentException("Property {$property} doesn't exist.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class nameClass{
    private static $_sData = [];
    private static $object = null;
    private $_oData = [];

    public function __construct($data=[]){
        $this->_oData = $data;
    }

    public static function setData($data=[]){
        self::$_sData = $data;
    }

    public static function Data(){
        if( empty( self::$object ) ){
            self::$object = new self( self::$_sData ); 
        }
        return self::$object;
    }

    public function __get($key) {
        if( isset($this->_oData[$key] ){
            return $this->_oData[$key];
        }
    }

    public function __set($key, $value) {
        $this->_oData[$key] = $value;
    }
}

nameClass::setData([
    'data1'=>'val1',
    'data2'=>'val2',
    'data3'=>'val3',
    'datan'=>'valn'
]);

nameClass::Data()->data1 = 'newValue';
echo(nameClass::Data()->data1);
echo(nameClass::Data()->data2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining `__callStatic` and `call_user_func` or `call_user_func_array` can give access to static properties in PHP class

Example:

```
class myClass {

    private static $instance;

    public function __construct() {

        if (!self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = $this;
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    public static function __callStatic($method, $args) {

        if (!self::$instance) {
            new self();
        }

        if (substr($method, 0, 1) == '$') {
            $method = substr($method, 1);
        }

        if ($method == 'instance') {
            return self::$instance;
        } elseif ($method == 'not_exist') {
            echo "Not implemented\n";
        }
    }

    public function myFunc() {
        echo "myFunc()\n";
    }

}

// Getting $instance
$instance = call_user_func('myClass::$instance');
$instance->myFunc();

// Access to undeclared
call_user_func('myClass::$not_exist');
```

Answer (score -1):

Also, you can get static properties accessing them like member properties, using __get():

```
class ClassName {    
    private static $data = 'smth';

    function __get($field){
        if (isset($this->$field)){
            return $this->$field;
        }
        if(isset(self::$$field)){  
            return self::$$field;  // here you can get value of static property
        }
        return NULL;
    }
}

$obj = new ClassName();
echo $obj->data; // "smth"
```

Comment: except that now it's public, so you don't even need `__get`

Comment: isset returns false if the field exists but is set to null. Better use property_exists

Comment: @RudigerW. Good point. i'd also recommend throwing an Exception instead of `return null` when no matching property is found, to follow behavior that would happen without the magic getter.

@JeffPuckett - i edited the answer to clarify :)