# Declaring a new static variable outside of Class

Tags: php, declaration, static-variables

Is there a way declaring new static variables outside of that class even if it's not set in class?

```
// Using this class as a static object.
Class someclass {
    // There is no definition for static variables.
}

// This can be initialized
Class classA {
    public function __construct() {
        // Some codes goes here
    }
}

/* Declaration */
// Notice that there is no static declaration for $classA in someclass
$class = 'classA'
someclass::$$class = new $class();
```

How can it be done?

Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done, because static variables, well... are **STATIC** and therefore cannot be declared dynamically.

**EDIT:**
You might want to try using a registry.

```
class Registry {

    /**
     * 
     * Array of instances
     * @var array
     */
    private static $instances = array();

    /**
     * 
     * Returns an instance of a given class.
     * @param string $class_name
     */
    public static function getInstance($class_name) {
        if(!isset(self::$instances[$class_name])) {
            self::$instances[$class_name] = new $class_name;
        }

        return self::$instances[$class_name];
    }

}

Registry::getInstance('YourClass');
```

Comment: How about declaring them with a static function inside that class? like `public static function set($class) { self::$$class = new $class(); }`

Comment: This isn't about context, **static variables can NOT be declared at runtime.** If you try it this way, you'll stil get a fatal error.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>`__get()` magic method in PHP is called when you access non-existent property of an object.</strike>

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

You may have a container within which you'll handle this.

Edit:

See this:

[Magic __get getter for static properties in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279382/magic-get-getter-for-static-properties-in-php)

Comment: This does not apply to static variables. A static variable is a property of a **CLASS**, not of an **OBJECT**.

Comment: So you are saying I cannot declare it even with a function inside of it? Example: `public static function set($class) { self::$$class = new $class(); }`

Comment: No, this applies only to class declaration, no way it can be done dynamically. Use static array property or so.