# Possible to test if a variable is static in PHP?

Tags: php, static-variables, magic-methods

Is it possible to test if a variable is static in PHP? I am trying create a magic method `__get` that also looks at static variables. I find that `property_exists()` returns true when a variable is static too. But I will need to use `::` instead of `->` I'd expect?

Comment: You mean class property/variable rather than local variable?

Comment: @BoltClock yes. a variable declared like `protected static $var`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magic __get getter for static properties in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279382/magic-get-getter-for-static-properties-in-php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to test if a variable is static via Reflection:

```
class Foo { static $bar; }
$prop = new ReflectionProperty('Foo', 'bar');
var_dump($prop->isStatic()); // TRUE
```

However, that still won't allow you to use them with magic methods `__get` or `__set`, because those only work in object context. [From the PHP Manual on Magic Methods:](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members)

> Property overloading only works in object context. These magic methods will not be triggered in static context. Therefore these methods should not be declared static. As of PHP 5.3.0, a warning is issued if one of the magic overloading methods is declared static.

Also see this discussion on the PHP Internals Mailing List about introducing `__getStatic`:

- http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=121875353105996&w=1

Comment: I managed to do it with something like `return static::$$prop` :) or is there something wrong with that?

Comment: @JM having to use late static binding and variable variables are not exactly indicators of good design. [Statics are death to testability](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/883-Stubbing-and-Mocking-Static-Methods.html) and [considered harmful](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0103_static_considered_harmful.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access undeclared static property using magic __get() method. It will raise PHP Fatal error. At least with PHP of version 5.3.

That's the result if you will try to access the property as static `ClassName::$propertyName` of course.

Comment: I declared it like `protected static $var` so its not undeclared?

Comment: @JM It is declared private, so it's like it's undeclared if you use it outside of the class