# Old Wordpress code got "creation of dynamic property is deprecated" warning

Tags: php, wordpress

I have designed a WordPress template for my site, and in the function file, I have used the following code to introduce style files to WordPress:

```
class JSXStyle {

  public function __construct( $name ) {
    $this->MyStyle = $name;
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'register_custom_style' ) );
  }

  public function register_custom_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( $this->MyStyle, get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/css/{$this->MyStyle}.css", array(), '4.0.0' );;
  }
}

new JSXStyle( 'style-1' );
new JSXStyle( 'style-2' );
new JSXStyle( 'style-3' );
new JSXStyle( 'style-4' );
```

This code works correctly. But when I installed the query-monitor plugin, this code got an error and displayed the following message:

**Creation of dynamic property JSXStyle::$MyStyle is deprecated**

I don't know how to edit this code to get rid of this error. Is there a way to update this code or should I use another method?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74879495/4225384) help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Warning Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74878889/php-warning-deprecated-creation-of-dynamic-property-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from PHP 8.2, [Dynamic Properties in object is deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration82.deprecated.php#migration82.deprecated.core.dynamic-properties). That means object properties should be declared before used in assignment (i.e. "creation of dynamic property").

Simply add the `JSXStyle::$MyStyle` property declaration would be enough:

```php
class JSXStyle {

  // Declare the MyStyle property before use.
  protected string $MyStyle;

  public function __construct( $name ) {
    $this->MyStyle = $name;
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'register_custom_style' ) );
  }

  public function register_custom_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( $this->MyStyle, get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/css/{$this->MyStyle}.css", array(), '4.0.0' );;
  }
}
```