# PHP catch calls to static parameter

Tags: php, parameters, static, call

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Magic __get getter for static properties in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279382/magic-get-getter-for-static-properties-in-php)

Is it possible to catch a call to a static parameter like this:

```
class foo
{
    public static $foo = 1;
    //public static $bar = 2; 

    public function catch_bar_call()
    {
        print "Calling an undefined property";
    }
}


print foo::$foo //1
print foo::$bar //error
```

instead of getting an error, i want a method to be called.
i know its possible trough __get() magic method, but you'll have to instantiate your class for this, not possible on static parameter.

Comment: I saw it, maybe someone knows a solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From PHP DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset)

> The $name argument is the name of the property being interacted with. The [__set()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) method's $value argument specifies the value the $name'ed property should be set to.
>
> Property overloading only works in object context. **These magic methods will not be triggered in static context**. Therefore these methods should not be declared static. As of PHP 5.3.0, a warning is issued if one of the magic overloading methods is declared static.

What i think you can do is

```
class Test {
    private static $foo = 1;
    // public static $bar = 2;
    public static function foo() {
        return self::$foo;
    }

    public static  function __callStatic($n,$arg) {
         print "\nCalling an undefined property $n";
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print Test::foo(); // 1
print Test::bar(); // Calling an undefined property bar
```

Output

```
1
Calling an undefined property bar
```

Comment: That handles the problem wihile calling a static function, but not calling a static parameter/attribute. try Test::$bar (it's not set and throws an error. what i want is to set a kind of listener to catch all calls on attributes/parameters, and react if an attribute is not persistant)