# dynamically created "protected static" variables in a php class

Tags: php, class, pdo, extends

```
class KD_DB extends PDO {
    protected static $dbOne = '';
    protected static $dbTwo = '';

    public function setVariable ($alias,$content){
        switch($alias){
            case'one':  self::$dbOne = $content;  break;
            case'two':  self::$dbTwo = $content;  break;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to create these dynamically?

Something like this to create the `protected static variables`

```
    public function setVariable ($alias,$content){
            self::${$alias} = $content;
    }
```

It did not work, but I suspect it is because I need it to be static to make it to work with a third class that extends this one...

Comment: Take a lool here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279382/magic-get-getter-for-static-properties-in-php

Answer (score 1):

If you only have the two variables, it may be easier (with more appropriate names) to set them using a `static function` for each one, something like...

```
class KD_DB {
    public static $dbOne = '';
    public static $dbTwo = '';

    public static function setOne ($content){
        self::$dbOne = $content;
    }
}

KD_DB::setOne("value for one");

var_dump(KD_DB::$dbOne);
```

(code with minor changes to show the process)

But if you wanted a more open ended method, I would go for an associative array as the static variables and then use the 1 method (like you currently are) to set the value in the array...

```
class KD_DB {
    public static $data = [];

    public static function setVariable ($alias,$content){
        self::$data[$alias] = $content;
    }
}

KD_DB::setVariable("three", "value for three");

var_dump(KD_DB::$data);
```

this method can have issues if you mistype a variable reference which should be found during testing though, but does offer flexibility.

Comment: I dont necessary only have two variables. It could be more, and it could be only one. 
A script containing a `foreach`-loop sets the `setVariable`-methood.

Comment: That is why I suggested the second method as an alternative.